# Abbreviating the string given in a list

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a *list of Names* which I want to abbreviate, but I want to know whether an inbuilt function exists for this.

eg:

```
John Doe -> JD
Jane -> J
```

I am trying something along the lines of this:

```
myListOfNames.ForEach(x => x = abbreviate(x));
```

I know I can create *my own function* to do the abbreviations, but is there a better way to do it using *inbuilt* functions?

Comment: You could use Linq to archive this...

Comment: So how your abbreviation look for this strings => `John S Doe` and etc. Is it `JSD` or only `JD`?

Comment: @er-sho JSD for John S Doe.
Is this possible using LINQ?

Comment: @Johnny what do you mean by archive and how can you do it?

Comment: And how about John de la Doe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we should *elaborate the rules*, e.g.:

1. Take at most `1` *capital* letter from each *word* (word is characters *between spaces*)
2. If word *doesn't have* capital letters, *skip* it (e.g. title `von`)
3. If word has *several* capital letters, take the *last* one: `D` in `McDonald`

**Implementation:**

```
  Func<string, string> abbreviation = (name) => string.Concat(name
    .Split(' ')                     // split to words
    .Select(word => word             
      .Where(c => char.IsUpper(c))  // only capital letters matter
      .LastOrDefault())             // take the last 
    .Where(c => c > 0));            // if word doesn't have capital letter, drop it

  ...

  string result = abbreviation("John McDonald");
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] Tests = new string[] {
    "John McDonald",
    "Baron von Munchausen",
    "Charles de Batz de Castelmore d'Artagnan"
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-50} -> {abbreviation(test)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
John McDonald                                      -> JD
Baron von Munchausen                               -> BM
Charles de Batz de Castelmore d'Artagnan           -> CBCA
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a matter of taking the upper case letter than it could be archived simply with `Linq`

```
string.Join("", "John McDonald"
    .Split(' ')
    .Select(w => w.First())
    .Where(c => char.IsUpper(c)));
//John McDonald = JM; Baron van Munchausen = BM
```

Comment: That would fail for McDonald wouldn't it?

Comment: This wouldnt work if the names arent saved with the first alphabet saved as upper case.

Comment: @Omkar but I assume First and Last name should start with uppercase. Otherwise you should reprocess your data and fix that.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but I still stand by my point of having to apply this method for non upperCase strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var result = name.Split(' ')
                        .Select(s => s.First())
                        .ToArray());
```

Comment: That would fail for Baron von Munchausen wouldn't it?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen no, it wouldnt. It should take BvM

Comment: I would think that the right abbreviation would not include "von" but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Split up your name with space and select the first letter of each split string.

Try below linq,

```
List<string> myListOfNames = new List<string>();
myListOfNames.Add("John Doe");
myListOfNames.Add("John S Doe");

var abbrs = myListOfNames.Select(x => string.Join("", x.Split(' ').Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()))).ToList();
```

**Note:** Assuming that your name separated with space.

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]